# How to implement structured / semantic logging in java?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, logback, slf4j

I am using logback for logging. We have a number of our own custom appenders to generate all the logs we need. Now we are looking into semantic logging. serilogj should work for our case. But I don't see extensive examples for this. Please suggest any other semantic logging framework for java (with support for custom appenders). Thank you.

Comment: Logback already has logger which has a hierarchical structure based on names, if you give meaningful you begin to have something :)